# How do I execute an SSIS 2008 package from .NET 4.0 Windows Service?

Tags: sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, ssis

I have a .NET 4.0 Windows service application (VS2010), I need to call an SSIS 2008 package.

I know that it is easier to create a web service and call that service from SSIS, I am not at liberty to do that.

So, I figured my next best option is to call my SSIS package from my windows service. I know in .NET 2.0 you can call the DTS package, and if i have SQL Server 2012 installed.

But I am not able to find a solution for this specific combination. .NET 4 and SQL server 2008 SSIS.

Or is there a way using the same combination that i can start and stop a windows service using SSIS 2008. And figure out when the windows service is finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the section *`Using a Web Service or Remote Component to Run a Remote Package Programmatically`* in the below MSDN documentation.

[*Loading and Running a Remote Package Programmatically*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx)

Comment: I cannot use a web-service...I have an existing windows service, plus I don't have the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS because of SQL 2008

Comment: Sorry, i see it now. However i still cannot use this solution, i cannot use web service.